# Paypal upload button does not accept zero quantities

Tags: paypal, forms

To simplify the problem I am trying to solve, let's say our customers want to buy any quantity of knives and/or forks.

Currently, we are using hosted buttons. We ask customers to add items one by one in the Paypal cart, then view the cart and check out.
The process is cumbersome and if one wants to buy large quantities, that's a discouraging lot of clicks.

I am trying to come up with a single Paypal button that sends over the contents of a simple order form.

The below works fine if *both* quantities are greater than zero. However, it does not work if someone wants to buy e.g. only forks and no knives.

I am considering using some Javascript to dynamically change the `item_name_x` attributes, moving out the way the ones whose quantity is zero (i.e. rename to `not_item_name_x`) and changing the rest to keep them in a sequence, but... I'm thinking there must be an easier way!

Also, I'm guessing this approach would rule out the ability to encrypt such buttons (dynamically).

Is there a better way around this? How would you solve this problem?

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@myshop.co.uk">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <table border=0>
      <tr id="fullprice">
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Knives">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="10.00">
          Knives:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" style="width:3em" name="quantity_1" value="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Forks">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="8.00">
          Forks:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" style="width:3em" name="quantity_2" value="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy with Paypal or card">
</form>
```

Comment: Your best bet is to use jQuery and listen for changes in quantity_x and if it becomes 0 move the input out of the form tag to a placeholder div tag, then if it becomes greater than 0 move it in again.

Comment: Thanks, though this is the kind of trickery I'm trying to avoid. Actually, that's not the end of the story. You need also to keep the remaining `_x` variables in a sequence, because if there are any gaps then the rest will be ignored by Paypal. In the example above, if I just move out the knives, I won't be buying any forks either. There must be a simpler solution to such a simple and presumably common use case.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of that. I guess that's why in many websites when you update the quantity of something, they just refresh the page and programmatically build the PayPal button form, much simpler.

Comment: Like another summary before they buy (on top of Paypal's)? I guess I could do that, but I don't see much difference. It's basically doing the same thing except using some CGI script (for example) instead of Javascript. Also, how would I encrypt the button? To me, it feels like something they could fix very easily on the Paypal side. Just accept zero quantities and exclude those from their summary.